# Opacity in a JavaFX Effect?

Tags: javafx, opacity

I'm trying to create a java code to display an isometric map.

It is simply a `3-dimensional table` displayed with some `for` loops.

I just finished a code that handles the distribution of light from certain sources. So, I know:

- It is not optimized
- It is not realistic
- Light travels behind some blocks (each block is unique, if it is illuminated from one side it will be in its entirety, etc.).

My question is:
I use some Effect ofJavaFX to change the hue and brightness of each block.
The problem is that as you see in the picture:

[image: Illustration]

With the progression of the light, I can change brightness / hue, but how to change the opacity? To ensure that the effect of light fades gradually, instead of becoming darker / orange like now?

Thank you !

PS1 : As you can see, the light on the rocks is ok, but the light on the grass is... Bad. I don't know exactly why the hue is making it like that. It is because the rock is only grey / white. So the hue doesn't affect it. So could I make it changes its color too ?

PS2 : I am a bit a noob, sorry. I'm sure it's a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOL ok, in fact use multiple effects, as gaussianBlur, sepiaTone and brightness level.

It makes it perfect ;)